# "Source" in bash vs csh

Tags: bash, unix, csh

I'd like to understand why sourcing a script in `csh` works but doesn't in `bash`. I have files for both `csh` and `bash` that set an `alias` for `jr` command.

`\bsource` for bash and `\csource` for csh

I have two scripts:

```
source \csource    
jr something
```

and this works like a charm, but:

```
source \bsource    
jr something
```

gives me

`jr:command not found`

Could someone please shine some light on it as I've searched far and wide to no avail.

Kind regards

BoB

Comment: What is the purpose of backslashes (`\csource`, `\bsource`)? You might as well write `csource` and `bsource` with the same success. Maybe `bsource` file sets the alias incorrectly. Show us the source.

Comment: I can drop the backslashes if it helps but as you said it doesn't make a difference. I am sure source files are fine because if I source them through command line `jr` works fine both in `bash` and `csh`. When sourced through script it works only in `csh`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bash, aliases are not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless `expand_aliases` option is enabled explicitly. Therefore, you should enable this option before sourcing a file with aliases:

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
source bsource
jr
```

Comment: Oh man, you've saved my day! Thanks a lot for prompt and accurate answer.

Comment: As an aside, the `bash` script should define a function (which are used in non-interactive shells) instead of an alias. `csh` doesn't have functions, so aliases serve the same purpose, but in `bash` you should almost always prefer functions to aliases.